# Installing Android Studio in MacOS Big Sur

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, macos-big-sur

I've been download Android Studio 4.2.2 from https://developer.android.com/studio
I drag & drop to Applications, then launch it, but it seems freezing like this: https://tppr.me/72TJM

Comment: See if it stopped responding from the `Activity Monitor`. How long have you been waiting for it to load?

Comment: `MacOS: ~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio4.1` delete that folder and start again

Comment: @DavidLee about 2 hours, i've been force quit and relaunch, but it seems crash : https://tppr.me/DCeP0

Comment: @UsamaAltaf You would need to explain what that does as the OP may not fully understand what exactly it does and what effects it may have.

Comment: @UsamaAltaf I've never been install AndroidStudion before, just 4.2 only https://tppr.me/NzQjS

Comment: @UsamaAltaf Well, respond to the OP WITH explanations with that link (as suggested by @Droid).

Comment: @vanio178 Seems like there was a discussion on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/jtbl4m/has_anyone_updated_to_macos_big_sur_and_is/) regarding the issue. You could take a look if solutions found on the link provided by Usama Atlaf don't work.

Comment: @DavidLee based on Reddit discussion needs to run `defaults write com.google.android.studio AppleWindowTabbingMode` , but I don't have any https://tppr.me/mY1O8